# Accessing the GRPC Service within docker-compose

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, grpc, envoyproxy

I am currently following the tutorial for [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers), and I decided to try to test out the GRPC functionality, similar to the project.

What I am trying to build is GRPC Client and GRPC Service, which are both hosted on docker and can talk to each other. Now, I managed to make it work, and if you look a the `Startup.cs` in GRPC Client, this Uri `http://host.docker.internal:5104` manages to make the call and get the response.

However, the original **eshopOnContainers** project uses the `http://basket-api:81` path, which is much nicer and in my opinion more maintainable. It also uses few more components and some configuration:

1. The GRPC Service uses the following in Startup.cs:
   `app.UsePathBase("/basket-api")` [Original project](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Basket/Basket.API/Startup.cs#L193-L197)
   and some configuration in Program.cs to listen to ports:

```
BuildWebHost
...
.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
        {
            var ports = GetDefinedPorts(configuration);
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, ports.httpPort, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
            });

            options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, ports.grpcPort, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
            });

        })
...
```

[Original project](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Basket/Basket.API/Program.cs#L42-L55)
The port for `httpPort` is 80 and for `grpcPort` 81.

2. The GRPC client uses the following Uri to make the call `http://basket-api:81`
3. In addition, there is an Envoy proxy also deployed, which has rules as follows, but what I believe the most important parts are rules `b-short`, `b-long`, and the cluster `basket`, which I believe results in the final URL being `basket-api:80` (as per cluster configuration).

I don't actually understand, why it would need port 81 if it ends up calling the GRPC service, but it would be nice if someone with more knowledge could explain.

```
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8001
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: eshop_backend_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: eshop_backend
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - name: "c-short"
                match:
                  prefix: "/c/"
                route:
                  auto_host_rewrite: true
                  prefix_rewrite: "/catalog-api/"
                  cluster: catalog
              - name: "c-long"
                match:
                  prefix: "/catalog-api/"
                route:
                  auto_host_rewrite: true
                  cluster: catalog
              - name: "o-short"
                match:
                  prefix: "/o/"
                route:
                  auto_host_rewrite: true
                  prefix_rewrite: "/ordering-api/"
                  cluster: ordering
              - name: "o-long"
                match:
                  prefix: "/ordering-api/"
                route:
                  auto_host_rewrite: true
                  cluster: ordering
              - name: "h-long"
                match:
                  prefix: "/hub/notificationhub"
                route:
                  auto_host_rewrite: true
                  cluster: signalr-hub
                  timeout: 300s
                  upgrade_configs:
                    upgrade_type: "websocket"
                    enabled: true
              - name: "b-short"
                match:
                  prefix: "/b/"
                route:
                  auto_host_rewrite: true
                  prefix_rewrite: "/basket-api/"
                  cluster: basket
              - name: "b-long"
                match:
                  prefix: "/basket-api/"
                route:
                  auto_host_rewrite: true
                  cluster: basket
              - name: "agg"
                match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  auto_host_rewrite: true
                  prefix_rewrite: "/"
                  cluster: shoppingagg
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.file_access_log
            filter:
              not_health_check_filter: {}
            config:
              json_format:
                time: "%START_TIME%"
                protocol: "%PROTOCOL%"
                duration: "%DURATION%"
                request_method: "%REQ(:METHOD)%"
                request_host: "%REQ(HOST)%"
                path: "%REQ(X-ENVOY-ORIGINAL-PATH?:PATH)%"
                response_flags: "%RESPONSE_FLAGS%"
                route_name: "%ROUTE_NAME%"
                upstream_host: "%UPSTREAM_HOST%"
                upstream_cluster: "%UPSTREAM_CLUSTER%"
                upstream_local_address: "%UPSTREAM_LOCAL_ADDRESS%"
              path: "/tmp/access.log"
  clusters:
  - name: shoppingagg
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: webshoppingagg
        port_value: 80
  - name: catalog
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: catalog-api
        port_value: 80
  - name: basket
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: basket-api
        port_value: 80
  - name: ordering
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: ordering-api
        port_value: 80
  - name: signalr-hub
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: ordering-signalrhub
        port_value: 80
```

## Issue

In my approach, I assumed that if I completely skip the Envoy proxy component and I call the service using `http://basket-api:80`, it would manage to find it, but unfortunately no luck. Now I am not sure whether my port is bad or whether my URI is bad, but I believe I am following a similar approach as in the original project just skipping the proxy.**

I might be also misinterpreting my Docker configuration, but I don't see any suspicious elements there.

## Error stack:

```
RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable (basket-api:81) SocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable (basket-api:81)
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11): Resource temporarily unavailable
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.DefaultConnectAsync(SocketsHttpConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp2ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Grpc.Shared.TelemetryHeaderHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)")
```

## Code

#### GRPC Client

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
 public void OnGet()
        {
            var response = _greeterClient.SayHello(new HelloRequest
            {
                Name = "Bob"
            });
            Debug.WriteLine(response.Message);
        }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddGrpcClient<Greeter.GreeterClient>((services, options) =>
            {
                // This one works
                //options.Address = new Uri("http://host.docker.internal:5104");

                // This one doesn't
                options.Address = new Uri("http://basket-api:80");
            });
        }
```

#### GRPC Service (default GRPC template with minor adjustments)

**Program.cs**

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                    {
                        options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                        });
                        options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 81, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
                        });
                    });
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddGrpc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UsePathBase("/basket-api");

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();

                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

#### Docker compose

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  grpcserver:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}grpcserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: GrpcServer/Dockerfile

  grpcclient:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}grpcclient
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: GrpcClient/Dockerfile
```

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  grpcserver:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:80
    ports:
      - "5103:80"
      - "5104:81"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
  grpcclient:
    environment: 
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "5121:80"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use docker generated DNS name from your docker-compose file. Your GRPC client should be able to reach the server on `http://grpcserver:5103`

With docker-compose you can talk between containers simply by using the name of the service and the port that you are exposing in the container.

[Edit]
Removed the extension from the path because UsePathBase()

> Adds a middleware that extracts the specified path base from request path and postpend it to the request path base.

[UsePathBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usepathbaseextensions.usepathbase?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: You are absolutely correct, and given your information, I have actually changed the URL being called to "http://grpcserver:81" and this absolutely works.

However, I have also verified one thing: I left by accident the original `            app.UsePathBase("/basket-api");` in the GRPC Service and yet the solution is still working using the above-mentioned URL. Do you possibly know, how is that possible?

Comment: I think I just figured it out: In the original solution, they are also combining the GRPC Service with WebAPI, which is where this thing is used. 

Anyway, thanks for the help and I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: It looks like that function removes that base path from the URL if it is present - which would be useful if your routes come in through a reverse proxy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usepathbaseextensions.usepathbase?view=aspnetcore-5.0